# How does List<T>.AddRange actually add the range supplied?

Tags: c#, list, addrange

I've looked around for a while now and can't seem to find any documentation that covers my concern.

I am wondering if I should ever be concerned with the order a range supplied to `List<T>.AddRange()` is added to the collection. I can assume all day that it will be added in the sequential order I supplied; that is, if I supply `0, 8, 5, 2, 9` it shouldn't ever be added in the order of `9, 5, 2, 0, 8` or anything other than `0, 8, 5, 2, 9`.

I've ran a test in a console application to determine the results using a post-increment in the `AddRange` method like so:

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 30;)
    test.AddRange(new int[] { i++, i++, i++ });

foreach (int i in test)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

This prints in sequential order as I expected it to from `zero` to `29`. However, my concern is that I'm unable to find documentation that shows me exactly how this range is added to the collection. I would assume that it would be something along the lines of:

```
foreach (int i in range)
    collection.Add(i);
```

Which would definitely preserve any order I've supplied, but I would like to ensure that this is actually what is occurring, or at least that what is occurring will never reorder the supplied range.

---

### NOTE:

Apparently I haven't had enough coffee yet today and missed it while looking over the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `AddRange`. Thank you all anyways, at least it's a great question for future readers that may be curious.

Comment: If you're that worried just look at the source code https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs  Or in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2)  it says _The order of the elements in the collection is preserved in the List<T>._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The order of the elements in the collection is preserved in the
>   List.

It's the first line under the section Remarks at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Yay skim reading for the win; I haven't had enough coffee yet apparently. Thanks!

Comment: I'll accept as the answer as soon as it will let me. 10 minute minimum I believe.

Comment: @PerpetualJ No worries, but thank you, I appreciate that.